# "Undefined index" error when accessing GET variable

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.4.6 with MySQL 5.5.27 and Apache 2.4.2.

My problem is that I'm trying to fetch the value of a URL passed variable using `$_GET` but an error always comes up stating: Undefined index: err in thispage.php at this line.

I looked around and realized that most of the developers solved that by using the `isset()` function. But this doesn't solve my problem because I need to get the actual value of the variable sent in the URL!

The URL is `http://localhost/Edugate/index.php?err=1`.

This is my code in the `index.php` page:

```
<?php
$error = $_GET['err'];

if($error == 1)
    print "<img src='icons/error.png' alt='error'> Icorrect usename or password...";
?>
```

Comment: You said `isset` doesn't solve your problem and you definitely need the value from the URL. Well, **if** the value was passed in the URL, you wouldn't be getting errors. Additionally, `isset` definitely solves your problem :)

Comment: You may want to read again about what `isset()` is / does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Check if there is a .htaccess file in that folder. It may be that a command in that file removes all get data. The code you posted should just work (although dirty)

Answer (score 4):

You could use something as simple as:

```
$error = isset($_GET['err']) ? (int)$_GET['err'] : null;

if ($error !== null) {
  // error
}

// or

if ($error === 1) {
} else if ($error === 2) {
}
```

Comment: thnxxxxx, that will solve the problem! I can't believe that I missed this concept!. I'm used to JAVA programming but it's been a while... PHP is a whole new thing for me so I probably need to read more as you stated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) as prescribed by your fellow developers.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['err']) && $_GET['err'] == 1)
    print "<img src='icons/error.png' alt='error'> Incorrect username or password...";
?>
```

*Incorrect *username, by the way.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I really appreciate it. the isset will solve half of my problem. Because let's say that the variables sent in the URL are going to by used in some kind algorithm in php. I still need to retrieve their values and I'm not finding a way to that..

Comment: @user1631838: Er, `$_GET['(parameter name)']` is how you get the values.